# Azure AD B2C and ADFS as SAML IdP. Code example?

Tags: azure, saml, adfs, azure-ad-b2c

I want users of my application authenticated in a couple of on-premises ADFS servers.

I setup Azure B2C working together with ADFS as SAML identity provider.

The setup process is described here in MS official docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-setup-adfs2016-idp

That was complicated, but now my custom policy B2C_1A_SignUpOrSignIn works, in meaning that it redirects to B2C login page with buttons first, then I click a button and system redirects to ADFS login page, where asks users for login and passwords.

But how to integrate it with a .NET or Node.js application?
Any code examples?

Comment: One important thing to mention that I need group clams available in SAML token from ADFS.

Answer (score 0):

Samples for different platforms can be found at [Azure Active Directory B2C code samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/code-samples).

If a sample application references a built-in policy, such as "B2C_1_SignUpOrSignIn", then you must replace this with your custom policy.

Comment: Thank you! I look through these, but there are no SAML examples there.

Comment: All of the code samples use OpenID Connect to integrate with Azure AD B2C because Azure AD B2C doesn't (publicly) support SAML RPs as yet. Do you have a particular preference for using SAML to integrate applications with Azure AD B2C?

Comment: My identity providers behind Azure B2C use ADFS with SAML (WS-Fed). Those ADFS provide group claims (information from active directory security groups membership). I do not know how to send these group claims using OpenID to my application. That's why I'm using SAML.